# Android. Memory usage limits

Tags: android, memory

I am using a 'big' in-memory data object in my Android app. Object size is ~3MB. It works fine on my device and emulator. Will  I have any unusual problems on weak devices?
Which objects are too big and which are fine to use in Android mobile application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the approximate memory allowed per application on a device via the `ActivityManager`'s `getMemoryClass()` function: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29

It returns an `int`, which specifies the approximate amount of memory available per app in megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search led me to the [Documentation from Google](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html):

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory